# How to add access checks to a method (and create a new method based on the "advised" method) with AspectJ?

Tags: java, security, aspectj, aop

Consider this code:

```
class DatabaseAction(/* ... */) {
  public void deleteUser(User userToDelete, User currentUser) {
    /* ... */
  }  
}
```

Is it possible to add an aspect-based annotation like `@Privilege(ADMIN)` to `deleteUser`, which

- adds an access check to the `deleteUser` method by checking if `currentUser` has the necessary privilege level `ADMIN` and throws an exception otherwise and
- adds an `deleteUserAllowed` method to the class which contains just the check (and no actual execution command) which returns a boolean whether the `currentUser` is allowed or not?

I know that it is possible to add methods to a class with Aspects, but I'm unsure if it is possible to add a method based on some other method name in the actual class.

In the end this is how I imagine that the code would look like after weaving in all aspects:

```
class DatabaseAction(/* ... */) {
  @Privilege(ADMIN)
  public void deleteUser(User userToDelete, User currentUser) {
    if (!<accessAllowed(ADMIN, currentUser)>) throw new InsufficientRightsException() 
    else // go on
    /* ... */
  }  

  public deleteUserAllowed(User userToDelete, User currentUser) {
    <accessAllowed(ADMIN, currentUser)>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but it seems like it might be a very narrow bit of Advice.

First, I'm assuming that the signature you give above is wrong, and that `User` is the class name for both `userToDelete` and `currentUser`.

Second, I'm assuming that, in this case, you're wanting to match on the second `User`, and not on the variable necessarily called `currentUser`.

Given those assumptions, however, where are other places that you would add this `@Privilege(ADMIN)` annotation? Would it still apply to the second `User` in those cases?

If you aren't clear on that question, perhaps you're using the wrong tool for the job here. (On the other hand, perhaps you're using exactly the right tool, and I'm just not yet understanding the question.)

EDIT:
A pointcut that would match the required task would look something like:

```
before(Privilege privilege, User user) : @annotation(privilege) &&
                                  call(* *.*(User, User)) && args(.., user) {
    if (!accessAllowed(privilege.getLevel(), user))
        throw new InsufficientRightsException()
}
```

Note that this only matches the case with exactly two User arguments. You can use `..` to allow more arguments before or after.

Also, make sure that your annotation uses `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`.

If what you're looking for is behavior that differs depending on return type, you can change the `call(* *.*(User, User))` to (for example) `call(void *.*(User, User))` and `call(boolean *.*(User, User))`. That said, the narrower your goals become, the less likely it is that an Aspect is what you want. If you want to figure out whether a user has access, I would just put that code in using normal Java. I.e., return `accessAllowed(ADMIN, user)`.

Comment: I fixed the signatures. Yes, maybe the restriction of the field name is too narrow. I plan to only us `@Privilege ` on methods having that "executing" user, because this is a crucial detail of the design. Basically the privilege level of the user decides whether the access is allowed.

Comment: Are you saying that for methods with the `@Privilege` annotation, you want to always perform your advice using the second `User`? What should your advice do if there isn't a second `User`, but there is the `@Privilege` annotation? It could possibly use the last `User` in that case, or nothing at all, but if the former, than what if there is an `@Privilege` annotation, but no `User` in the signature? (Since the pointcut would include the signature, it's easy to ignore such situations, but you _might_ want to throw an error.)

Comment: Yes, I would have to do some error checking, but that's currently not my focus. I try to find out how to do it at all at the moment...

Comment: Ok, cool! I got it to work. But how would I add an additional method `deleteUserAllowed` to the class?

Comment: @soc: I don't understand what difficulty you're having in adding that additional method. Assuming that you don't want it captured by the pointcut, don't use the `@Privilege` annotation.

Comment: Ben Hocking: I don't know how to do it in the ApectJ syntax. The method should basically hold the same access checks and return true/false instead of executing the command.